# What do I do with nominee shares I got from a crowdfunding "investment"?

Tags: investing, shares, crowdfunding

I am not an investor and it all goes a bit beyond me and that's why the things I've found on Google on this topic don't really add up for me. Years ago I "invested" in a company that I like on Crowdcube and got some goodies out of it — as you would on e.g. Kickstarter. I also got a PDF stating that I am **the beneficial owner of X fully paid ordinary shares (nominee) in the company, subject to the Memorandum and Articles of Association of said company**.

The fine print:

> These shares are held on trust for the person named above by Crowdcube Nominees Ltd (Registered Company Number 09820478)
> (or any successor or assignee) (the “Nominee”).
> This document is not a share certificate in the above named company and serves as a statement of beneficial ownership. The beneficial
> shareholder named above is not included in the company’s share register in respect of this beneficial shareholding. The Nominee shall be
> included in the company’s share register as legal owner. This statement is not intended to serve as evidence of beneficial or legal
> ownership and any questions and notices regarding beneficial ownership rights, including entitlement to beneficial ownership and transfer of
> beneficial ownership should be addressed to the Nominee at support@crowdcube.com. The Nominee shall maintain the register of
> beneficial ownership as final evidence of ownership.

Am I right in saying that I have no power with dealing with those shares that I am the beneficial owner of? Can I sell it and make a profit? Who's got the money I sent out originally?

Comment: Stupid question, but did you send an email to the one shown in the statement above so they could tell you the answer?